# Add a plugin to my site

Tags: css, plugins

I am looking to add some sort of plug-in that will let me drag png images around the page and drop them in another location. similar to this : http://www.astleyclarke.com/uk/bracelets/create-your-own-charm-bracelet

Can anyone help?

thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

use jquery sortable plugin or draggable plugin 
[click Here (sortable)](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)! 
or [here (draggable)](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)  or [here for ( dropabble)](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) 
it will provide you all the functionalities that you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery **[dropable photo manager](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)** plugin which will be perfact as per your requirement.

else there are tones of dragable plugins are available. From them [draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/) is really very popular and efficient...

You can find some basics explaination [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) for jquery ui. :-)